# ExtJS: Opening and closing ComboBox with Array Store behaves strange

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, store

I try to add values dynamically to a ArrayStore, and show these values in a ComboBox.

My store looks like:

```
'Selection' : Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
    storeId : 'selection-store',
    fields  : [
        { name : 'id', type : 'string' },
        { name : 'name', type : 'string' },
        { name : 'elements', type : 'array' },
        { name : 'properties', type : 'array' }
    ]
})
```

I add things to the store with the following code:

```
var selection = {id : id, name : id, elements : elements, properties : []};
Stores.Selection.add(selection);
Stores.Selection.commitChanges();
```

and my ComboBox looks like

```
xtype        : 'combo',
store        : Stores.Selection,
displayField : 'name',
valueField   : 'name',
emptyText    : 'Choose Selection...',
id           : 'selection-dropdown',
editable     : false
```

So now when I add some values into the store, and I look into the store (e.g. via FireBug), everything I added is in the items-Array, as it should be.
But as soon as I expand the ComboBox, the store gets cleared and is empty afterwards; the ComboBox is also empty.

But when I expand and close the ComboBox before adding something to the store, and then start to add things, it behaves like it should behave (the values get stored and the ComboBox shows the value's names).

I'm Using ExtJS 4.1 and I have no idea, where this strange behaviour could possibly come from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might need to change your combo's `queryMode` attribute to keep it from trying to recreate the store when the combo is opened.  This seems to work for me.

There's a fiddle here with this code:  http://jsfiddle.net/cfarmerga/KvUd2/

```
Ext.onReady(function() {    

    var selection = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
        storeId : 'selection-store',
        fields  : [
            { name : 'id', type : 'string' },
            { name : 'name', type : 'string' },
            { name : 'elements', type : 'array' },
            { name : 'properties', type : 'array' }
        ]
    });

    selection.add({ id: 1, name: 1, 
                    elements: ['a', 'b'], properties: ['x', 'y']});
    selection.add({ id: 2, name: 2, 
                    elements: ['a', 'b'], properties: ['x', 'y']});
    selection.add({ id: 3, name: 3, 
                    elements: ['a', 'b'], properties: ['x', 'y']});
    selection.commitChanges();

    Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        border: false,
        margin: '10 10 10 10',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'combo',
                fieldLabel: 'Combo',
                name: 'combo',
                labelWidth: 50,
                width: 300,
                displayField: 'name',
                valueField: 'name',
                emptyText: 'Choose selection...',
                editable: false,
                store: selection,
                queryMode: 'local'
            }
        ]
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! I would never have thought of that!